# How do I get my app to appear in Google Now's Phone Search list?

Tags: android, google-now

I want my app to be able to handle search requests from Google Now and appear in its Phone Search list, but I can't find any documentation on this.  Does anyone have a link they can offer up?

Comment: Is this a Voice Command? Which one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add your application to the Phone Search in Google Now by setting

```
android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"
```

in your `searchable.xml` configuration file per the [Searchable Configuration reference page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html). Google Now shares the same phone search options as previous versions of Android, which was often called [the Quick Search Box](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introducing-quick-search-box-for.html). You'll probably also want to reference the [Search Suggestions for the Quick Search Box training](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html#QSB).

Comment: So if I want, for example, my app to respond to searches that start with "listen to…" by searching for a music track, that would be handled by android:searchSuggestIntentData ?

Comment: @Seanonymous - that would be something different: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/supporting-new-music-voice-action.html

Comment: I have added this attribute but still my app is now showing in the "Phone search" list...

Comment: @slott - from the Searchable Configuration reference page I linked to in my answer: "The user must still enable your application as a searchable item in the system search settings before your suggestions will appear in Quick Search Box." - make sure you do that as well!

Answer (score 4):

I, too, was looking for how to do this.

Turns out, adding your app to global search no longer works in KitKat and was removed in this commit: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/QuickSearchBox/+/ecf356c15143ab0583c64682de16d94a57f7dd1c

Comment: See [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20001979/3055345) for details about this.

Answer (score 1):

Your searchable.xml needs to contain a few vital attributes before this will work. Simply adding the include global will not work. The sample app has a complete searchable.xml that works:

The ones that I have found to be mandatory for the search to show up in the "Phone search" list is:

```
android:searchSuggestAuthority
```

and

```
android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"
```